# How do I sort an integer array while also keeping identical elements apart from each other?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm not sure if there's a name for this type of sort so I'm struggling to find any relevant answers elsewhere.

I want the elements to rotate as much as possible.

Given this array:

[38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 60]

How do I sort it into this?

[38, 40, 41, 60, 38, 40, 41, 40, 41, 41]

I've research other threads and have not been able to find the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4].uniq.sort*4

Comment: Your problem isn't completely well defined yet.

How, for example, would you sort:  [1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]?  There is no way to not have multiple 3s next to each other and still keep all the original elements.  Or are you only sorting counts of numbers?

Comment: I'm trying to evenly rotate them as much as possible. Here's a (hopefully) clearer example: Given this: [38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 60], I want this: [38, 40, 41, 60, 38, 40, 41, 40, 41, 41]

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a "sort", per se. There's a sorting *step*, but ultimately what you're really trying to do is called a [**matrix transposition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Two ways of accomplishing that are below.

## More verbosely

The first way is longer and is broken down into more steps for clarity (hopefully).

First, we'll sort and group the related array elements together:

```
v = arr.sort.group_by { |e| e }.values
# => [[38, 38], [40, 40, 40], [41, 41, 41, 41], [60]]
```

Let's make a new array for the result:

```
r = []
```

Now we'll get the one with the largest number of elements:

```
max = arr.map { |e| arr.count(e) }.max
```

Then we'll loop through the array that many times,

```
max.times { ... }
```

pulling one element from each subarray each time, then putting it onto the result array:

```
max.times { v.each { |a| r << a.shift } }; r.compact!
```

and we have our answer:

```
# => [38, 40, 41, 60, 38, 40, 41, 40, 41, 41]
```

## More concisely

Now that you've seen the long way, here's a more concise approach. This doesn't require as much iteration (or an output array!).

First, we fill the subarrays to a size of `max`:

```
arr.sort.
  group_by { |e| e }.values.
  map { |a| a.fill(nil, a.size..max-1) }
# ...
```

This is now a square array of size `max` by `max` elements, so we can treat it as a square matrix. That means we can transpose the elements so that the "rows" become the "columns", and vice versa.

So we'll `transpose`, then `flatten` to get a single array, then `compact` to get rid of the `nil` elements:

```
# ...
  (...).transpose.flatten.compact
```

and we get the desired result:

```
# => [38, 40, 41, 60, 38, 40, 41, 40, 41, 41]
```

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into this! It really helped me. I do want to mention that I still had nils using the verbose way until I dropped to the next line & used r = r.compact(). I guess compact returns a copy without the nils. Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveArnold: Whoops, I left off an `!`; that should be `r.compact!`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to this. Looks like John already gave a nice answer, so I'm not going to explain this verbosely.

To learn how this works I suggest to putting in some `puts` statements to see the intermediate values. You can run it with `watch ruby sorter_test.rb` to constantly get feedback. (See [watch docs](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_watch.htm)).

Most of the methods used here are from the [`Enumerable` module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html).

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Sorter < Struct.new(:list)
  def call
    sorted_and_grouped = list.sort.group_by { |i| i }.values
    max_len = sorted_and_grouped.max_by(&:count).count
    padded = sorted_and_grouped.map { |xs| pad(xs, max_len) }
    padded.reduce(&:zip).flatten.compact
  end

  private

  def pad(xs, len)
    xs.fill(nil, xs.count...len)
  end
end

ORIGINAL  = [38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 60].freeze
SORTED    = [38, 40, 41, 60, 38, 40, 41, 40, 41, 41].freeze
class TestSorter < Minitest::Test
  def test_sorts_as_expected
    actual = Sorter.new(ORIGINAL).call
    assert_equal SORTED, actual
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. It depends on your array being ordered (increasing or decreasing), as it is in your example. Moreover, the problem is not well-defined without that assumption.

First, a helper I've often wished for:

```
class Array
  def %(arr)
    arr.each_with_object(dup) do |e,a|
      i = a.index(e)  
      a.delete_at(i) if i
    end
  end
end
```

For example:

```
arr = [38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 60]
arr % [41, 60, 40, 38, 40, 41] 
  #=> [38, 40, 41, 41]
```

If `a` and `b` are two arrays, `a%b` is similar to `a-b`, except rather than removing all elements of `a` that are contained in `b`, it removes one character in `a` (the one with the smallest index) for each instance of that character in `b`.  Now wouldn't this be a handy method to have as a built-in?

With this helper it's a simple matter to sort the array in the manner desired:

1. Make a copy `a` of the array and create an empty array `result`.
2. Add `u`, the unique elements of `a`, to `result`.
3. Remove `u` from `a` using the helper.
4. If `a` is empty, return `result`; else repeat step 2.

The code for this is as follows:

```
def steves_sort(arr)
  a = arr.dup
  result = []
  while a.any?
    u = a.uniq
    result.concat(u)
    a = a % u
  end
  result
end

steves_sort([38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 60])
  #=> [38, 40, 41, 60, 38, 40, 41, 40, 41, 41]
```